# Any alternative to Sendkeys class in c#

Tags: c#

I am sending keystrokes using SendKeys.SendWait() method to another active application.

But it Seems that SendKeys have some timming and inconsistensy problem.
SendWait method will not wait for messages to be processed when they are sent to another process.

Can anyone suggest any alternative for sending keystrokes to other application(active) in C#.

Comment: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ I have not used it and I don't know if it will allow you to overcome the limitation you mentioned, but it is some alternative to check out.

Comment: I have found a way to eliminate the inconsistency issue related to Sendkeys.Send() or Sendkeys.SendWait() method.

 
Use " Thread.Sleep(500) " statement after Every " Sendkeys.SendWait() " so that the application will wait for some time and in the meanwhile the messages will get processed.